# Is there a way to have PyLint flag 'Yoda conditions'?

Tags: python, pylint

In some Python code I'm working on I spot here and there so-called '[Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)'.

Examples are:

```
if 0 < len(someList): ...

if None != ComputeSomething(): ...
```

Is there a way to have them flagged by PyLint?

Comment: Well they should both be changed more than simply reversing the comparison; `if someList:` and `if ComputeSomething() is not None:`!

Comment: That's another good point. But once they've been flagged up, it'd be easy to do that :)

Comment: What about `if 2 < len(somelist) < 5:`? Is that a semi-yoda?

Comment: I'd argue that's a Luke. Something like `-1>>2 < 0.5 < 1 >> 0` (True) or `-1>>2 < 0.5 < 1 >> 0 < 1` (False) is Darth :)

Comment: I get `5 == foo`, but `5 < foo` … I've always ordered `<` conditions in order of increasing value; I visualize them on a number line mentally, increasing in value from left to right.

Comment: Yuck.  This check makes (some) sense for equalities, but comparisons? `x1 < x2 + h and x2 < x1 + h` is fine; why would `0 < x2 + h and x2 < h` be an issue?

Comment: Glad they are called Yoda conditions because Yoda was a smart cookie.  Putting the constant on the left hand side makes sure you don't make a mistake and make it an assignment.  `400 = something` would generate a syntax error in C where `something = 400` would always be true, and since I code in multiple languages my habits leak from one to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pylint currently implements this as convention check C0122, [starting with v1.5.0 (2015-11-29)](http://docs.pylint.org/changelog.html):

> Add a new convention message, ‘misplaced-comparison-constant’, emitted when a constant is placed in the left hand side of a comparison, as in ‘5 == func()’. This is also called Yoda condition, since the flow of code reminds of the Star Wars green character, conditions usually encountered in languages with variabile assignments in conditional statements.

From the [features documentation](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html):

> **misplaced-comparison-constant (C0122):**
>
> *Comparison should be %s* Used when the constant is placed on the left side of a comparison. It is usually clearer in intent to place it in the right hand side of the comparison.

Example output:

```
C:130, 3: Comparison should be __name__ == '__main__' (misplaced-comparison-constant)
```